# Install Wireguard CLI without homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I am building an application that creates VPN tunnels using wireguard.

Currently wireguard is available as CLI only through `brew` or `port`. ([Official Download Page](https://www.wireguard.com/install/#macos-homebrew-and-macports-basic-cli-homebrew-userspace-go-homebrew-tools-macports-userspace-go-macports-tools))

To avoid installing homebrew, I downloaded pre-built binaries from [here](https://bintray.com/homebrew/bottles)

But that throws "unidentified developer" error and fails to run.

How do I fix this? Does it need signing or is there something else homebrew seems to be doing which I can replicate?

Or is there a 3rd party option for signed wireguard binaries for macOS (couldn't find through Google).

Thanks!

Comment: Location of bottles.. https://bintray.com/homebrew/bottles

Comment: You should always be able to get applications directly from the vendor/developer, or compile them from source yourself. To help with your specific issue described in the question, please add the specific steps you took (idealy by copy/pasting the corresponding Terminal in/output as text) and where/how it failed.

Comment: Hi @nohillside ! Thanks for the reply. I was referring to wireguard. In their site they have GUI from App Store. But CLI is only from brew or port https://www.wireguard.com/install/ ... No presigned binaries... So I downloaded their bottle with the binary but it did not work...

Comment: Please **edit** the question to add the details I asked above.

Comment: @nohillside changed the whole thing to reflect my exact case now. tnx.

Comment: We can‘t see over your shoulders so please share details. What happens between the download and the error message you got? Did you just run from Terminal, did you install it first (and how), is the error in Terminal or in a dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to open your binaries.
2. Open System Preferences.
3. Go to Security & Privacy and select the General tab.
   [image: unblock app]

[Source](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-app-unidentified-developer-3669596/)